# Android: async task An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

before use Async Tasks my code is work. So i have done some changes in my code and now progress bar is showing up but getting the below errors.

Log cat:

```
08-07 06:43:15.875: E/AndroidRuntime(1734): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-07 06:43:15.875: E/AndroidRuntime(1734): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-07 06:43:15.875: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-07 06:43:15.875: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-07 06:43:15.875: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-07 06:43:15.875: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     ... 18 more
```

mycode:

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            final EditText eKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxt_key);
            inputs = eKey.getText().toString();
            if (inputs.matches("")) {

            } else {
                keys = url + inputs;
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(keys);
                try {
                    satu = json.getJSONObject(TAG_1);
                    String two = satu.getString(TAG_2);
                    String three = satu.getString(TAG_3);
                    if (two.matches("") | three.matches("")) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("not found!").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                 eKey.setText("");
                                 status.setText("Key not found!");
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else {
                        Intent x = new Intent(MainActivity.this, result.class);
                        x.putExtra("bac", two);
                        x.putExtra("cab", three);
                        startActivity(x);
                        eKey.setText("");
                        keys = "";
                        inputs = "";
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

What is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the complete logcat please

Comment: show what you have coded in `doInBackground()`

Comment: You cannot update UI from `donInBackground()`, use `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask` to perform `setText()` etc..

Comment: @JibranKhan i try, but error is same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
alert.show();
```

and

```
eKey.setText("");
```

cannot be performed in background task. Pass a return value from

> doInBackground()

to

> onPostExecute()

method and perform UI tasks there.

Answer (score 2):

You should not keep any UI related element inside `doInBackground()`

For example, 
If you are downloading any staff from network, at that time you want to update UI , you can use `onProgressUpdate()` to update UI and implement `publishProgress() @doInBackground().`

Otherwise, 
AsynTask is running in separate worker thread to execute staff behind UI using `doInBackground()` method (We can show loading dialog when Asyntask running in background). Once work is done, we can update UI using `onPostExecute()`.

If you need more clarification on AsynTask, sure u can shot your questions...

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

AsynTask class provides three main methods :

- *onPreExecute()*
- *doInBackground()*
- *onPostExecute()*

the two methods *onPreExecute()*, *onPostExecute()* are executed in the same thread of the class which contains the UI.

The method *doInBackground()* is executed on a different thread. As we cannot refer to UI from a process that is running on a different thread, we can :

- move our code (which refers to UI) to the *onPostExecuted*() method
- use [handlers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) (a way to refer to UI also from a different thread if we need)

Bye :)